# Add values in a two-dimensional array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to merge and add the following 2D array:

```
var arr = [
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TEN", 10],
    ["FIVE", 5],
    ["ONE", 1],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["DIME", 0.1],
    ["DIME", 0.1],
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["PENNY", 0.01]
    ];
```

Resulting in a 2D array that looks like this:

```
 arr = [
     ["TWENTY", 80],
     ["TEN", 10],
     ["FIVE", 5],
     ["QUARTER", 0.50],
     ["DIME", 0.20],
     ["PENNY", 0.04]
     ];
```

Basically I'm adding up the number values and condensing the string values. I tried map, reduce, and for loops but this one has me stumped.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? I mean, show us some code.

Comment: Write a for loop that iterates array1, then inside the for loop, use a switch and then increment designated array2 entry with the corresponding value from array1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need is a reduce and a map, which could probably add up to a good [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) joke.

```
var arr = [
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TEN", 10],
    ["FIVE", 5],
    ["ONE", 1],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["DIME", 0.1],
    ["DIME", 0.1],
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["PENNY", 0.01]
];
var obj = arr.reduce(function (out, el) {
    out[el[0]] = (out[el[0]] || 0) + el[1];
    return out;
}, {});
var out = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    return [key, obj[key]]
}); //[["TWENTY",80],["TEN",10],["FIVE",5],["ONE",1],["QUARTER",0.5],["DIME",0.2],["PENNY",0.04]]
```

Comment: @MichaelLaszlo Thanks for the catch, probably didn't notice it since the code still works for integers. However it breaks for floats. Fixed.

Comment: By the way, `|` doesn't add integers either.

Comment: @MichaelLaszlo Yes it does, you can confirm it in your console. The reason why the typo works to begin with is that you can use the binary operation `|0` to cast things into integers in Javascript, much like how you can ensure something is a number by using `||0`.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. `(2 | 2) == 2`. `2 + 2 == 4`.

Comment: Oh I see where your confusion stems from. In the above code, that's not what it's meant to do. The plus sign is used to add the results together. Doing `foo || 0` ensures that the result is a number, whether foo is undefined before or not. That allows us to avoid `undefined + 2 === NaN` and instead we have `(undefined || 0) + 2 === 2`. The same holds for `(undefined | 0) + 2 === 2` given foo is undefined, but only for integers because `(2.5 | 0) === 2`.

Answer (score 2):

You have an array with `key, value` tuples. You can iterate over these tuples, store each new key in an object, and increment the value as you come upon subsequent tuples the same key. If you keep an array of keys in the order in which you encountered them, you can map the array of keys to a result array.

But it would be foolish to go to all this trouble when you could use the purely functional approach shown in Nit's answer.

Below is the ugly approach. Don't do this. Do what Nit says.

```js
function addArray(tuples) {
  var hash = {},
      keys = [];
  tuples.forEach(function (tuple) { // Iterate over [key, value] tuples.
    var key = tuple[0],
        value = tuple[1];
    if (hash[key] === undefined) {  // Is it a new key?
      keys.push(key);               // Then add it to keys.
      hash[key] = value;            // And set the initial value.
    } else {
      hash[key] += value;           // Otherwise, increment the value.
    }
  });
  return keys.map(function (key) {  // Map the keys to tuples.
    return([key, hash[key]]);
  });
};

var arr = [
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TEN", 10],
    ["FIVE", 5],
    ["ONE", 1],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["DIME", 0.1],
    ["DIME", 0.1],
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["PENNY", 0.01],
    ["PENNY", 0.01]
];

var added = addArray(arr);

added.forEach(function (tuple) {
  document.write(JSON.stringify(tuple) + '<br />');
});
```